# Матрицы преобразования

Tags: 3d, преобразование, матрицы

Есть массив точек x,y,z составляющих некоторую фигуру. Нужно сделать возможность перемещать, масштабировать и поворачивать эту фигуру. Сделал, проблем с переносом нет, есть проблемы с масштабом и поворотом. Дело в том что фигура поворачивается\масштабируется относительно верхней левой точки экрана, а мне нужно относительно центра объекта. Преподаватель сказал, что чтобы это правильно работало, нужно вернуть объект в начало координат, восстановить поворот, масштаб, умножить на текущую матрицу преобразования и умножить на прошлые повороты\масштабы\переносы.

В связи с этим возникает вопрос, в какой последовательности делать преобразование к начальному состоянию? Я сделал функцию, которая возвращает объект матрицы. Выглядит примерно так

```
return matx * -move * -rot_x * -rot_y * -rot_z * scale.inv()
```

где `move` единичная матрица с текущим положением, `rot_?` матрица поворота по каждой оси, `scale` инвертированная матрица масштаба. После этого я эту матрицу умножаю на текущее преобразование. После передаю в другую функцию, которая её умножает на

```
scale * rotz * roty * rotx * move
```

и возращает результат. В итоге поведение получается странное и не правильное. Может я что-то перепутал или не так понимаю?

Плюс ещё одна проблема что мне приходится хранить повороты и масштаб отдельным полем в коде чтобы вернуть всё в начало, т.к. на перенос не влияют масштаб и поворот. Можно ли какие-нибудь из матрицы вытащить текущий вектор3 для масштаба и поворота или это не предоставляется возможным?